# _set_printf_count_output() appears broken under Windows 7

Tags: c, windows

Microsoft in their infinite bloody wisdom have by default disabled the %n specifier in printf (and all variants thereof).

You can re-enable it with this function; _set_printf_count_output().

I have used this - some time ago in the past - and it worked.

Now it isn't working.  Platform is latest SDK on Windows 7.

Anyone else finding this?

Comment: Just curious, what is a practical use case for this?

Comment: David Heffernan, that edit to my OP was unnecesary.  "Microsoft in their infinite bloody wisdom have by default..." is not grossly offensive.

Comment: I have an array of integers.  I want to print them to a string.  The code is a loop, with this as the body; wsprintf( string+offset, L"%u%n", *(array+loop), &count); offset += count;

Comment: @Blank I know it's not grossly offensive. It's just that you'll likely get better answers if you are less confrontational. If you object strongly you can always rollback!!

Comment: @David: right now, I -am- annoyed with MS, because they've done something annoying AND they seem to have broken the way to fix it, so I -do- object strongly.  Talk to me tomorrow and I'll prolly feel differently.

Comment: @Blank: Better solution would be to use `snprintf`, which returns number of characters printed. That does the same w/o using unsafe `%n` format + checks for errors.

Comment: @Vlad: ta, I hadn't realised the safe functions returned number characters written.

Comment: @Vlad: `snprintf` is not a good substitute for `%n`. It requires breaking up your format strings into multiple parts, and unless you know the output length is bounded by a small number, you're going to have to call `snprintf` once with `n=0` to get the length, and `printf` to actually do the printing. (And, oops, `snprintf` with `n=0` does not work right on Windows...!) Believe it or not, `%n` actually is very useful.

Comment: @R..: Assuming it could be useful, which you haven't convince me of, as there are tons of alternative solutions to this not utilizing possible security vulnerabilities, it is definitely not useful in this case as `snprintf` solves a problem almost with zero code change.

Comment: `%n` is not a potential security vulnerability any more than any other use of pointers in C. The vulnerability is the act of passing an untrusted string as a format string. While it's unlikely that format strings without `%n` will lead to non-DoS security compromises simply due to the nature of implementations, as soon as you pass an invalid format string, *the program has undefined behavior* and *anything*, including privilege compromise, could happen!

Answer (score 2):

Program:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int count;
    _set_printf_count_output(1);
    printf( "1234567890123456%n78901234567890\n", &count);
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123456789012345678901234567890
16
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi))</sub>

Comment: (32 bit??  and you're an MD - tell your minions to fetch an upgrade ;-) :-)

Comment: I'm at home. I have 64 bit at the office. It's an 8 core. Widescreen, dual monitors, the works